Error parsing file: Element {http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata}apiVersion invalid at this location in type Document
I created an excercise lwc project, when I run the command sf project deploy start  -d force-app/main/default/lwc to deploy lwcs, it works fine and components can be all deployed, but if I run sf project deploy start  -d force-app/main/default/classes to deploy a apex class, it failed saying Error parsing file: Element {http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata}apiVersion invalid at this location in type Document for all the lwcs deployed successfully by the previous command. My lwcs are under folder lwc, apex classes under classes folder.
the js-meta.xml has no special as below
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" >

    <apiVersion>61.0</apiVersion>

    <isExposed>true</isExposed>

    <targets>

        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>

        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>

        <target>lightning__HomePage</target>

    </targets>

</LightningComponentBundle>

OS: win 11
Node.js: 20.8.1
sf: 2.29.5
